# Memory occupied by STP instruction

Tags: assembly, arm64

Assume the following instruction:

```
stp x29, x30, [sp, -32]!
```

assuming the stack pointer is at address 0, then what address `x29` and `x30` are stored:

- option 1: `[sp-16]` and `[sp-32]`
- option 2: `[sp-32]` and `[sp-40]`

I know the stack grows towards low addresses, but whenever storing we occupy towards growing addresses, hence i think 'option 1' is the right answer.

what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of addressing modes, memory accessess of more than 1 byte always *start* at the given base address and ascend, so your "option 2" with one part either side of the base address is clearly not right. Also beware that an initial stack pointer of 0 would be invalid given that you're trying to store *below* it - the result of an address calculation which underflows or overflows is architecturally unknown, so whilst some hardware might happen to produce the expected address, you definitely shouldn't rely on it.

In this case, if for example the initial `sp` was 0x1000, then you'd have the bytes of the first register (`x29`) stored to addresses 0x0fe0..0xfe7 (in the appropriate order for the current endianness), the bytes of the second (`x30`) stored to 0xfe8..0xfef, and finally 0xfe0 written back to `sp`.